# Golang: Why os.Exit doesn't work inside goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a research program with very simple algorithm. When success is coming goroutine should be close (end) via os.Exit(0). I'm wait one day, two day.... What? :)

Here is the simple code

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    for {
        go func() { os.Exit(0) }()
    }
}
```

And my questions:

1. Why os.Exit doesn't terminate the goroutine?
2. What is correct way to terminate (stop) goroutine execute?

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/GAeOI-1Ksc

Comment: Are you sure that's the reason? Because the given code finishes fine for me. In any case, have you tried simple `return`?

Comment: I don't know where you tried, but on my computer this code doesn't finish. I don't know how to use `return` with goroutines. All calculates inside goroutine and result can't be "return".

Comment: `go func() { return }()` ?

Comment: And I know (after manual calc) success result are missed... Because os.Exit didn't work when is needed.

Comment: I added a playground link for show my code logic (just structure example)

Answer (score 20):

You've run into a sticky corner of the Go scheduler. The answer is that `os.Exit` *does* cause the entire process to exit, but the way you had it, the goroutines were never running.

What probably happened was that the for loop kept adding new goroutines to the list of available goroutines, but since the entire process was only running in one OS thread, the Go scheduler never got around to actually scheduling a different goroutine, and just kept running that for loop without ever running any of the goroutines you'd spawned. Try this instead:

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    for {
        go func() { os.Exit(0) }()
        func() {}()
    }
}
```

If you run it on the Go Playground, it should work (in fact, [here's a link](https://play.golang.org/p/KS3MwEPjkO)).

OK, the fact that the above code works while yours doesn't should be pretty mysterious. The reason this works is that the Go scheduler is actually non-preempting. What that means is that unless a given goroutine voluntarily decides to give the scheduler the option to run something else, nothing else will run.

Now obviously you've never written code that includes commands to give the scheduler a chance to run. What happens is that when your code is compiled, the Go compiler automatically inserts these into your code. And here's the key to why the above code works: one of the times that a goroutine might decide to run the scheduler is when a function is called. So by adding the `func() {}()` call (which obviously does nothing), we've allowed the compiler to add in a call to the scheduler, giving this code the opportunity to schedule different goroutines. Thus, one of the spawned goroutines runs, calls `os.Exit`, and the process exits.

**EDIT**: The function call itself may not be sufficient in the event that the compiler inlines the call (or, in this case, removes it entirely since it does nothing). [`runtime.Gosched()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched), on the other hand, is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Or you can change GOMAXPROCS to something >1 and it will work without modification. Pretty obvious one when you find out that  GOMAXPROCS is 1 in the playground.

Comment: Actually that's probably not it. If he's running go1.5, GOMAXPROCS defaults to the number of CPU cores he has (almost certainly more than 1). The issue is that GOMAXPROCS is not the number of OS threads to run - it's the *maximum* number of OS threads to run, and if there's only one running at the beginning, his code will never kick the scheduler into spawning new ones.

Comment: (he said "I'm wait one day, two day.... What?", which makes me think he was running it on a computer, not just on the playground).

Comment: Thanks. I modify my example as you proposed, but without success http://play.golang.org/p/Io8NUXh0UR (Process took too long)

Comment: I think you're just getting unlucky with the process taking a while; check out what happens when you change the constant to 10: https://play.golang.org/p/SkZzYHC_on

Comment: Well, as I understand it, GOMAXPROCS lets you define exact number of OS threads that will be used as processors i.e. execution units for goroutines. When I was reading about the scheduler I did some tests with infinite loops and how it affects the program depending on GOMAXPROCS value. And GOMAXPROCS > 1 solved deadlocking everytime. Why wouldn't, that the whole point. And on older go runtimes, maybe even just before 1.5 GOMAXPROCS was always equal to 1 regardless of available CPU cores

Comment: It's not the exact number, but the maximum. But you're right that the default used to be 1.

Comment: About compiler inserting scheduler calls. That doesn't work as simple as that. It will only insert calls if there is a function call. Compiler might inline the function  or throw it away completely and you will get deadlock. When I did my tests I had to disable inlining and had to make pretty big function before it started working as it supposed to.

Comment: May be maximum but it shouldn't give you deadlock it such a simple case. And it's not unrealistic either.

Comment: I can't in real program to increase or decrease "compared" values, It's undefined. How I can will stop goroutines when inside is Boolean `true`? :)

Comment: That's true, but in a real program the runtime won't kill your process if you run for a bit too long ;)

Comment: Guys, I don't know about "GOMAXPROCS", I'm started learn Go week ago. I use 1.5.2 (last) version. My code very-very similar as http://play.golang.org/p/Io8NUXh0UR but compared values undefined.

Comment: Can you give us a more realisic example? As for GOMAXPROCS, checkout this http://play.golang.org/p/pbEC7J3133 Only thing I changed is added `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)` Now it works like it should

Comment: @creker - I know that the function might be inlined, but apparently it wasn't ;)

Comment: @joshlf, but it still unreliable. I changed count to 2 and it still deadlocks. Playground keeps killing the process. Check out this https://play.golang.org/p/Dk0VFzyYEQ I ran it many times - `show` doesn't get called even ones. Good thing is in real applications there will be real function calls and even blocking ones so everything will work fine even with GOMAXPROCS=1

Comment: I think the only thing happening here is that the playground is getting pissy about how long it's running, but it's not actually deadlocked - try running it on a real computer.

Comment: I tried - had to reboot my PC. It deadlocked and kept spawning goroutines until my RAM was filled and whole OS just froze. Of course I launched it with GOMAXPROCS=1. So, no, scheduler call is not inserted in that case. My example above shows that goroutines don't get a single chance to run

Comment: More real example in http://play.golang.org/p/XvebObOhDA - diff with my code only in numbers size, I'm using big.Int. All yours proposed ideas I tried on real computer (every time modify my code) but without success.

Comment: Hmm ok. Try `time.Sleep(1)` instead.

Comment: @AL: that last example doesn't work, because main is exiting before anything happens.

Comment: @JimB it's not true. Because if you modify last example to  http://play.golang.org/p/WSFozjw65Z (marked THIS LINE ADDED) and run `go run code.go > res.txt` you will see result.

Comment: @joshlf Where I should add this line? And I don't like stop every iteration even on the 1 sec. Because speed is important.... `Billions iterations * 1sec != not good idea`, imho :)

Comment: @AL: so the scheduler gets a chance to switch goroutines before exiting. There's nothing unexpected here. Realistic code which doesn't spawn a possibly infinite number of goroutines,  and then waits for them to finish will *always* works as expected.

Comment: @JimB I say to you Thank you, and for all guys, but I'm not ready to learn "how work scheduler" and I need in one thing: how to terminate goroutine, when inside is TRUE? :) Thanks.

Comment: OK, technically the best thing to do would be [`runtime.Gosched`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched).

Comment: @AL: that still isn't the correct solution, since there is no guarantee that the goroutine will run at all. My previous comment wan't about learning how the scheduler works, it was about creating a deterministic logic flow in the program.

Comment: Sorry @JimB. My last reply is not aggressive, my brain work very hard to understand one thing and my criticism to Golang only. I thinking simple - programming lang must be simple, and shouldn't brake the work or take the "golden time" to learn. Thanks. )

Comment: @AL: that's fine, but Gosched is almost always the wrong answer. If you wanted to know why os.Exit wasn't being called in this specific case, then you need to know something about the scheduler. If you want to know how to do it correctly, then you have some sort of synchronization to ensure your goroutines execute, and all this talk about the scheduler is moot.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. Synchronization is "dark forest" for me :) I think about channels, but I don't have a time to learn that. Maybe later...

Comment: @AL I think what @JimB is saying is that if you use proper synchronization (for example, channels), you won't have to understand how the scheduler works to know that your program will work correctly. That said, I agree that if you only want a quick-and-dirty solution that will work for your purposes right now, `runtime.Gosched` will do that for you. But in the long run, you'll probably want to figure out how to do this sort of thing with channels.

Comment: @AL: then see my answer for a solution without channels. You simply cannot use concurrency without synchronization -- it can't work. joshlf, like I said before, Gosched might make the program work more often on a specific version of the runtime, but there's still no guarantee that the goroutines will run to completion, or at all.

Comment: @AL, go IS simple. When you write proper idiomatic code using goroutines and channels everything will just work. But what's simple on the surface is  complex on the inside. Golang simplicity is about complexity of the runtime and how much it does for you. So when you find an edge case like this one you have to dig deeper to understand what's going on. Deadlocking and goroutines starvation is an edge case when you have an infinite loop without function calls and your GOMAXPROCS=1. It's a known one and expected but hard to understand without understanding the basics of go scheduler.

Comment: @AL, can you please post the output of `fmt.Println(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(0))` on your machine.

Comment: News: **1.** GOMAXPROCS = 4 **2.** Gosched works, but a) very slow, slower than without goroutine b) as I see Gosched didn't use all processors, or merge goroutines to "stream" - like line **3.** Later I try to modify my code with channels. **4.** Also I have a plan write to Dave Cheney or Dmitry Vyukov, maybe anyone write about this problem for newbies :D.... See later.

Answer (score 0):

You terminate a goroutine by returning from the function. If you need to ensure that the goruotine runs to completion, you need to wait for the goroutine to complete. This is usually done with a `sync.WaitGroup`, or by synchronizing the goroutines via channels.

In your example, you first need to ensure that there is no possibility of spawning an infinite number of goroutines. Because there's no synchronization points between `main` and the new goroutines, there's no guarantee that any of them will execute the `os.Exit` call while the main loop is running.

The usual way of waiting for any number of goroutines to complete is to use a `sync.WaitGroup`, which will ensure they have all executed before `main` exits.

```
wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() { defer wg.Done() }()
}

wg.Wait()
fmt.Println("done")
```

Comment: JimB, I added a playground link in the topic, can you view and modify my example for success work? Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

Implement a deadhand or kill switch

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
        "os"
)

const maxNoTickle = 50          // will bail out after this many no tickles
const maxWorking = 20           // pretendWork() will tickle this many times
const deadTicks = 250           // milliseconds for deadHand() to check for tickles
const reportTickles = 4         // consecutive tickles or no tickles to print something

var (
        tickleMe bool           // tell deadHand() we're still alive
        countNoTickle int       // consecutive no tickles
        countGotTickle int      // consecutive tickles
)

/**
*       deadHand() - callback to kill program if nobody checks in after some period
*/
func deadHand() {
        if !tickleMe {
                countNoTickle++
                countGotTickle = 0
                if countNoTickle > maxNoTickle {
                        fmt.Println("No tickle max time reached. Bailing out!")
                        // panic("No real panic. Just checking stack")
                        os.Exit(0)
                }
                if countNoTickle % reportTickles == 0 {
                        // print dot for consecutive no tickles
                        fmt.Printf(".")
                }
        } else {
                countNoTickle = 0
                countGotTickle++
                tickleMe = false        // FIXME: might have race condition here
                if countGotTickle % reportTickles == 0 {
                        // print tilda for consecutive tickles
                        fmt.Printf("~")
                }
        }
        // call ourselves again
        time.AfterFunc(deadTicks * time.Millisecond, deadHand)
}

/**
*       init() - required to start deadHand
*/
func init() {
        time.AfterFunc(250 * time.Millisecond, deadHand)
        tickleMe = true
}

/**
*       pretendWork() - your stuff that does its thing
*/
func pretendWork() {
        for count := 0; count < maxWorking; count++ {
                tickleMe = true // FIXME: might have race condition here
                // print W pretending to be busy
                fmt.Printf("W")
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
        }
}

func main() {
        go workTillDone()
        for {
                // oops, program went loop-d-loopy
        }
}
```