# Why aren't my goroutines launched?

Tags: go, goroutine

No, it's not because my program ends too fast.

I have this script:

```
package main

import ("log"; "io/ioutil"; "strings")

const BASE_FILE_NAME = "abc_"

func mygoroutine(file_name string) {
    log.Println("In goroutine for file", file_name)
}


func get_file_names() []string {
  file_names := make([]string, 0)
  files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("./")
  for _, file := range files {
      if strings.HasPrefix(file.Name(), BASE_FILE_NAME) {
        file_names = append(file_names, file.Name())
      }
  }

  return file_names
}

func main()  {
    file_names := get_file_names()
    for _, file_name := range file_names {
        log.Println("Now lunching goroutine for file", file_name)
        go mygoroutine(file_name)
    }

    log.Println("Finished launching.")

    for {}

    log.Println("Now exiting")
}
```

In the directory that contains the executable, I have two files that start with `abc_` so the output is this:

```
2016/03/04 20:35:14 Now lunching goroutine for file abc_fr
2016/03/04 20:35:14 Now lunching goroutine for file abc_hrty
2016/03/04 20:35:14 Finished launching.
```

The script doesn't stop, it never logs `Now exiting` , because it loops in the empty for. But I do not see the `In goroutine for file` message.

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If `GOMAXPROCS=1`, `for{}` freezes your program without ever letting it switch goroutines. `select{}` doesn't do that and doesn't eat CPU.

Comment: You could use a `WaitGroup` instead of the `for {}` loop - see http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Right before seeing your comment, I changed the for {} with time.Sleep() and it worked. I will change GOMAXPROCS now and see what that does.

Comment: Actually, even when GOMAXPROCS>1 `for{}` will eventually block the scheduler altogether when the GC tries to stop the world. Never use a busy loop.

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34885000/2363866 And maybe google about go scheduler, there're some great blog posts and golang team design documents. It's actually not as simple as `busy loop  freezes your program`. It can freeze in some case, in other cases it will work even with GOMAXPROCS=1 and without blocking operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your program is running with `GOMAXPROCS=1` (that is, a single OS thread), `for{}` freezes it without ever letting Go's user-mode scheduler run. [This is the issue about it](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/543). JimB points out it causes other problems regardless of `GOMAXPROCS`; eventually the runtime has to stop your goroutine for garbage collection, and it can't stop `for{}`.

Changing `for{}` to `select{}` lets the scheduler run and doesn't eat CPU. [In this reduced program, your goroutine code runs](http://play.golang.org/p/c5qaYLHHH6). It ends with "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!" because your other goroutine quits and the only remaining one (main) is hung in the `select{}`.

```
package main

import "log"

const BASE_FILE_NAME = "abc_"

func mygoroutine(file_name string) {
    log.Println("In goroutine for file", file_name)
}

func main() {
    go mygoroutine("foo")
    log.Println("Finished launching.")
    select {}
    log.Println("Now exiting")
}
```

Of course, you normally don't want to hang a goroutine even with `select{}`; that's going to leave some resources in use until your program ends. To build something useful you'll need something else like a [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) or channel.

Comment: @RandomGuyqwert - please accept this answer so that others may see the working solution